# Why pingpong program execute fails sometimes using pipe?

Tags: c, pipe

In `pingpong.c`,I want to send a byte to child process and in the child it prints "ping",and the child sends one byte to parent process and in the parent it prints "pong". After running `make`, I can run `pingpong` command in command line.Now it cannot execute. Could anyone please expalains it to me?

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user/user.h"

int main(int argc,char* args[]){
    
 int p[2];
 pipe(p);
 char[1] buf;

 if(fork()==0){
        read(p[0],buf,1);
        printf("%d: received ping\n", getpid());
        close(p[0]);
        write(p[1],buf,1);
        close(p[1]);
        exit(0);
 }else {
        write(p[1],buf,1);
        close(p[1]);
        wait(0);
        read(p[0],buf,1);
        printf("%d: received pong\n", getpid());
        close(p[0]);
        exit(0);
 }
}
```

Comment: One possible issue: `printf` is line buffered so it may not output immediately without a newline character. Either add a `\n` at the end of each `printf` string or explicitly `fflush`. If that is not the problem then please describe what "it fails" means exactly.

Comment: Also, does this code actually compile? Some of it is not valid C syntax (e.g. `char* [] args` and `char[1] buf;`) and it also includes some non-standard headers.

Comment: Unrelated but your `printf` format string appear to be incorrect. You just have a `%d` while you are also writing `buf`

Comment: You might like to use `strace` or to insert some more `printf()` to see what each process does, where it hangs, and so on. -- BTW, `buf` is not initialized when sent by the parent.